# what is the integral $\int_{\Gamma}(x+y)dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

let $\Gamma$ be  a closed  differentiable contour  oriented counterclockwise  and let $\int_{\Gamma} \overline{z}  dz = A$

what is the integral $\int_{\Gamma}(x+y)dz$

(where $x$ and $y$ respectiveley are the real and imaginary part of $z$) in term of $A$?

My attempts :  i take  $z=re^{i\theta}$ now  $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$

$\int_{\Gamma}(x+y)dz=\int_{\Gamma}(r\cos\theta +r\sin\theta r) ie^{i\theta}d\theta$

after that im not  able to proceed further

pliz help me

thanks u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could substitute $x=\frac{1}{2}(z+\overline z),y=\frac{1}{2i}(z-\overline z)$ into the integral and use $\int_\Gamma zdz=0$.  The last equality is because $\Gamma$ is closed and $z$ is holomorphic.

Comment: thanks u  @user254433

Comment: but one more doubt @user254433,,, how $\int_{\Gamma} zdz =0 $  ? can u elaborate that more

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Goursat theorem? Even if not, there's an easy proof in the following article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_theorem

Comment: thanks u @user254433